# Issue with copying down formula to entire column after finding nonempty cells from a Google Form response sheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-forms, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I have a Google Sheet that holds the responses from a Google Form. In the sheet, there are 6 columns that only ever have an answer in one of them (depending on the answer they pick in the previous question, it takes them to one of 6 pages, all six pages are for the same thing). I am referencing that data in another sheet (same file) with a formula that finds the nonempty cell and returns it. The issue is I need to copy this formula down for the entire column, but every time there is a new entry, it makes the formula reference the next cell down (so if it was looking at C2:N2, it shifts it down to C3:N3).

I have tried using Arrayformula with an If/Isblank combination, and an Index/Match combination, but neither really work. Here are both of them: Arrayformula method:

```
=arrayformula(IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!C2),IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!D2),IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!E2),IF(ISBLANK('Form Responses 1'!F2),'Form Responses 1'!G2),'Form Responses 1'!F2),'Form Responses 1'!E2),'Form Responses 1'!D2),'Form Responses 1'!C2))
```

Index/Match Method:

```
=INDEX('Form Responses 1'C2:G2,MATCH(TRUE,INDEX(('Form Responses 1'C2:G2<>0),0),0))
```

The issue with the first method is that when I try to change the last half to `'Form Responses 1'!C2:C` so that it will fill the entire column, it will only use the column that was selected in the very entry for all of the rest of the entries (so if the value selected in the first row was from column D, it would only copy down from column D for the rest of them, regardless if they are blank or not). The issue with the second method is that it only does it for one row at a time, and still has the issue of the form entries changing the formula. I have found similar cases online, but none exactly fix my issue.

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to due to the information on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

paste this formula into the first row:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(C2:N);;999^99))))}
```